# Remember me function between sessions

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences

When I click on the 'remember me' checkbox, based on the codes it will save the username and password by `sharepreferences`. However,  when I exit my application and go back, the username and password will disappear.

How do I save the username and password between sessions?

```
// Remember me function
        CheckBox cbRemember = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkRememberPassword);
        if (cbRemember.isChecked()) {

            // save username & password
            SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                    "PREFS", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences
                    .edit();
            editor.putString("UserName",
                    String.valueOf(txtLogin.getText().toString()));
            editor.putString("Password",
                    String.valueOf(txtPassword.getText().toString()));
            editor.commit();

        }
```

Comment: Can you post how are you getting back data from shared preference?

Comment: i only have this sharepreferences to save. but i do not know how to retrieve it. Because when i press the back button in android phone, it exited the application. And when i go back to the app, the username and password disappear.

Comment: So without retrieving data from the shared preferences how could you say it not in shared preference?

Comment: what's the code to retrieve? sorry i'm new to android.

Comment: Look at the answer of Paresh Mayani, Its describe how to retrieve shared preferences, Now when you come back to your app just fetch data from shared preferences and display in your views..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you exit the app and go back, the `onResume()` method will be called. It's the place where you should put Paresh Mayani's codes to retrieve the username and password. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to understand the lifecycle of an activity in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Same as you have put username and password strings inside the shared preference, you can retrieve the same by doing as below:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS",0);
settings.getString("UserName", "");  
settings.getString("user", "");
```

But i think for implementing remember me functionality, just put a boolean flag whenever the login is successful:

```
 editor.putBoolean("login",true);
```

and retrieve whenever app is re-started next time:

```
settings.getBoolean("login", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the Activity.MODE_PRIVATE flag use instead getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE) flag.

Comment: NO, its not necessary, If you want to make shared preference as private for only your app, then MODE_PRIVATE is used.

Comment: so what's the conclusion? which coding should i change?